# javascript: variable defined vs function undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = ["one", "two"];
array2 = ["two", "four"];
```

If I write:

```
var inetersection = array1.filter(function(n){
    return array2.indexOf(n) != -1 
 });
```

I get the right answer: "two".

But if I write a function:

```
function intersection (array1, array2){
   array1.filter(function(n){
   return array2.indexOf(n) != -1
   });
}
```

then `console.log(intersection(array1, array2));`returns `undefined`

what is wrong with the second syntax?

Comment: `intersection` returns nothing

Comment: oops, very obvious, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything. How do you fix it:

```
function intersection (array1, array2){
   return array1.filter(function(n){
       return array2.indexOf(n) != -1
   });
}
```

### Why?

So variables have a value, let's start with this:

```
var hello_world = "Hello World!";
```

That this is doing is it's setting the value of `hello_world` to `"Hello World!"`. That's simple enough.

---

## Explanation!

Now let's try it with a function.

```
function addNumbers (number_1, number_2) {
    number_1 + number_2;
}
```

Now let's run that function

> `addNumbers(1, 2)`
>   `undefined`

Why do we get `undefined`? Let's go back to the first example and type something like that into the console

> > "Hello World!"
>
> "Hello World!"

What's happening is when we type the string `"Hello World!"` it *retuns* the string. This rule is preset in JavaScript but when you make your own functions, it doesn't know what to `return` the reason is, lets take jQuery for example. You can do:

```
var elem = $("#element");
```

Let's look at the first part. So there is a function called `$`, that function is probably doing a lot of stuff. First, it's getting the element with the `id` `element`. It stores that element in `elem`. The function might be doing a lot of stuff but it isn't *`returning`* anything. Returning something is setting the value of a function. Here are two examples:

```
var function_1 = function () {
    alert("Hello!");
};

var function_2 = function () {
    return function () {
        alert("Hello");
    }
}
```

Now what the heck did I just do in function two? Here's what

```
var variable_1 = function_1();
console.log(variable_1);
```

> `undefined`

`variable_1` is undefined but it still alerted. This is because it ran the function but it returned undefined. So `variable_1` isn't a function; because `variable_1` is undefined. Let's look at `function_2`

```
var variable_2 = function_2();
console.log(variable_2);
```

> ```
> function () {
>
>    alert("Hello");
>
> }
> ```

```
variable_2(); //Alerts "Hello!"
```

This is also a bit confusing because `function_2` *returns* a function, it sets `variable_2` to the function returned. That's why this works fine.

---

Hope that made sense. [Here's a MDN page on `return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 5):

Your function `intersection` returns nothing

Just add a `return` to line 1 of your function

Answer (score 0):

The intersection function does not have a return statement. 
You need to do this:

```
function intersection (array1, array2){
   return array1.filter(function(n){
      return array2.indexOf(n) != -1
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a return before the array.filter invocation.

```js
var array1 = ["one", "two"];
var array2 = ["two", "four"];

function intersection(array1, array2) {
  return array1.filter(function(n) {
    return array2.indexOf(n) != -1;
  });
}

console.log(intersection(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add return before `array1.filter` to be

```
function intersection (array1, array2){
   return array1.filter(function(n){
   return array2.indexOf(n) != -1
   });
}
```

> > Note : This method is a JavaScript extension to the ECMA-262 standard; as
> >     such it may not be present in other implementations of the standard.
> >     To make it work you need to add following code at the top of your
> >     script:

```
   if (!Array.prototype.filter) { 
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/)   {
         var len = this.length;
         if (typeof fun != "function")
           throw new TypeError();

         var res = new Array();
         var thisp = arguments[1];
         for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
         {
           if (i in this)
           {
             var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
             if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this))
               res.push(val);
           }
         }

         return res;   }; }
```

[Javascript Array filter() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_filter.htm)